# Storing and Query Blank Values in Hive Columns

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a requirement for storing blank strings of length 1, 2, and 3 in some columns of my Hive table.

Storing:

1. If my column type is char, then I see that the data is always trimmed before storing. i.e. length(column) is always 0
2. If my column type is varchar then the data is not trimmed. so length(column) is 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
   So that solves my storing problem.

Querying:

1. I am unable to query the column by value.
   say. `select * from hive table where column = '  ';`
   it only works if I do something like
   `select * from hive table where length(column) > 0 and trim(column) = '';`

Is there a way to handle this separately ?
say I want to query those records where  column value is of a blank string of length 3? How do I do this?

This is what i Tried (Note that the issues seems to be when the file is stored as parquet)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DUMMY5 (
  col1 varchar(3)) 
  STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION "/DUMMY5";

insert into DUMMY5 values ('  '); // 2 character strings
insert into DUMMY5 values ('   '); //3 character strings

select col1, length(col1) from DUMMY5;
+-------+------+--+
| col1  | _c1  |
+-------+------+--+
|       | 3    |
|       | 2    |
+-------+------+--+

select col1, length(col1) from DUMMY5 where col1 = '  '; // 0 record
select col1, length(col1) from DUMMY5  where col1 = '   '; // 0 record
```

Comment: Char types are similar to Varchar but they are fixed-length meaning that values shorter than the specified length value are padded with spaces but trailing spaces are not important during comparisons

Comment: And value is trimmed in Hive if it length is bigger (silently wo exception). And for varchar column all spaces are significant, comparing like col='   ' should work fine

Comment: i updated my question to add the code i had tried...

Comment: tested.  Col4 works as expected, returns one row. Maybe your Hive version is not stable? Use STRING - it will work without trimming

Comment: analysed some more. the table was stored as parquet. code snippet added to main question

Answer (score 0):

Running Hive 2.1.1

```
drop table dummy_tbl;
CREATE TABLE  dummy_tbl (
  col1 char(1),
  col2 varchar(1),
  col3 char(3),
  col4 varchar(3)) ;
  
  insert into dummy_tbl values ('  ', '  ', '  ', '  ');
  
   select  length(col1),  length(col2),  length(col3), length(col4) from dummy_tbl;
```

Result:

```
c0  c1  c2  c3
0   1   0   2
```

Varchar column works absolutely correct. col2 was [trimmed on insert, it is documented](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-VarcharvarcharVarchar).
col4 varchar(2) works correctly, this query returns 1:

```
 select count(*) from dummy_tbl where col4='  '; --returns 1
```

And length of all char columns shows 0 and comparison ignoring spaces like it is [documented](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-CharcharChar):

```
select  count(*) from dummy_tbl where col1=' '; --single space --returns 1
select  count(*) from dummy_tbl where col1='  '; --two spaces --also returns 1 because it is ignoring spaces
```

You can use `varchar` with proper length. Or `STRING` type if you not sure about length.

Comment: tried some more. and this is what i found. The data was stored as parquet. That causes the issue. Updating the code in my question.